# Watin Help - Fileupload under VISTA

Tags: upload, file-upload, watin

I'm trying to upload a file using Watin and C#. Under Windows XP, Watin opens the Filebrowse window and selects the file properly, but under Vista the Browser window pops up but no file is selected. Could you help getting this to work under Vista? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which Watin version are you using? I also had some difficulties with upload under Vista(using Watin rtw). But since using Watin beta 2.0 (March 30, 2009) uploading works without problems. So first check if you have the newest version where they fixed that bug. 
If that is not the issue, could you give us some code sample?